# Changing Values of Bool Variables When Two Strings have same value

Tags: c#

hi guys sorry i'm new to c# and don't quite know my way around it yet i'm making a windows forms Application in c# and i want to change a bool variables value to true when two string variables have the same values and false when then don't thank you

Comment: Use `String.Equals` e.g. `bool equal = String.Equals(string1, string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Answer (score -1):

```
 bool myvariable=CompareString("Hello","Hello")

CompareString is a Method which compares two given strings and returns boolean value.


 public bool CompareString(String sampel1,String Sampel2) /*not  Case Sensitive */
    {
    return sampel1==sampel2;
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to invent a new method for an existing one?

Comment: Your "not Case Sensitive" method is actually case sensitive - and sensitive to `null`s. Frankly, `return sampel1 == Sampel2;` would have been a better implementation, but we don't exactly need a new method for that

Comment: @TimSchmelter:Not Necessary!Taut to be better way so Ryan Understands.

Comment: @restless because `==` is so unclear by itself? Also: `CompareString` is a terrible name. Compare *how*? Most times that the word "compare" is used, it refers to inequality / order purposes, not equality.

Comment: @MarcGravell:Updated!